Kernel of formal derivative of noncommutative polynomial(or power series) ring over characteristic $0$ field.
Suppose $k$ be a field of characteristic $0$.
Let $R$ be a noncommutative polynomial(power series) ring over $k$ generated by formal variables $X, Y$. i.e.,
$$R = k \langle 1, X, Y, XY, YX, X^2, \dots \rangle$$ as a vector space, and canonical multiplication by $X, Y$ is given.
Now define a formal derivative $\partial_X, \partial_Y$ naturally. They are derivation : Linear, noncommutative Leibniz operators.
Then, I would like to prove that $\ker \partial_X \cap \ker \partial_Y$ can be iteratively constructed by multiplication, $[X, -] : R \to R$ and $[Y, -]:R \to R$ which are formal Lie brackets. It means that, for any degree $n$ monomial $Z$ in $\ker \partial_X \cap \ker \partial_Y$, it could be represented by the sum of multiplication of $[X, L]$'s and $[Y, L']$'s where $L, L' \in \ker \partial_X \cap \ker \partial_Y$ of lower degree.
For instance, $$[X, [Y, X]][X, Y] + [X, Y][Y, [Y, X]]$$ is in $\ker \partial_X \cap \ker \partial_Y$
How would I prove this problem? I thought it was simple to prove, but I don't know now.

Are you sure you have the statement in the question correctly? $1$ is in the common kernel, but elements of $[X, \ker \partial_Y]$ and $[Y, \ker \partial_X]$ cannot have constant part.

@VladimirLysikov You are right. $1$ also be the generator.

This is a particular case of Theorem 7.15 in my The signed random-to-top operator on tensor space, arXiv:1505.01201v2. Specifically, you need to let $L = k^2$ (your $k$ is my $\mathbf{k}$), and identify the noncommutative polynomial ring with the tensor algebra $T\left(L\right)$ of $L$. What I call $\overline{\mathfrak{g}}'$ is the span of the nontrivial nested Lie brackets; thus $\left(\overline{\mathfrak{g}}'\right)^\ast$ is the subalgebra of $T\left(L\right)$ generated by such brackets. Proposition 7.4 (b) in op. cit. is saying that $\operatorname{Ker} \mathbf{t}'$ is the set of all noncommutative polynomials $U$ whose directional derivatives $\partial'_g\left(U\right) = 0$ are all zero. Of course, this is equivalent to saying that all their partial derivatives are zero, since any directional derivative is a linear combination of partial derivatives.
I think §7 of my note is self-contained and can be read without the preceding sections, except for some lemmas whose proofs are omitted due to analogous proofs appearing in previous sections. Most of these lemmas make easy exercises anyway.
Eight years after finishing this note, I am still wondering if the results are known. Where did your problem come from?

Thanks for your notes. The problem arose from trying to prove the BCH formula in Lie algebra theory. My attempt failed, but I still found it interesting, so I asked about it
